# Why does this MySQL Select take forever

Tags: mysql, sql-server, forever

Good Evening,
I have this query and i can't manage to fix it. It never finishes but it finishes on MSSQL 2000, i want to have it on MySQL. Any advice ?

```
SELECT T_Coll.Nom_REGION AS Region_Col,
       T_Coll.Nom_STE AS Societe_Col,
       T_Coll.Nom_ETS AS Ets_Col,
       T_Coll.Nom_CDP AS CDP_Col,
       T_Coll.ID_Coll,
       T_Coll.NomColl AS NomColl,
       T_Coll.Nom_Coll AS NOM,
       T_Coll.Prenom_Coll AS Prenom,
       T_Coll.Trig_Coll,
       T_Coll.EXTERN,
       T_DETAIL.AN,
       T_DETAIL.Mois_Modif,
       T_DETAIL.T_AFFAIRE_ID,
       T_DETAIL.T_LOT_ID,
       T_DETAIL.T_SOUS_LOT_ID,
       T_Type.NomType,
       T_DETAIL.AUTRE_LIBELLE,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR01 + T_DETAIL.JOUR02 + T_DETAIL.JOUR03 + T_DETAIL.JOUR04 + T_DETAIL.JOUR05 + T_DETAIL.JOUR06 + T_DETAIL.JOUR07 + T_DETAIL.JOUR08 + T_DETAIL.JOUR09 + T_DETAIL.JOUR10 + T_DETAIL.JOUR11 + T_DETAIL.JOUR12 + T_DETAIL.JOUR13 + T_DETAIL.JOUR14 + T_DETAIL.JOUR15 + T_DETAIL.JOUR16 + T_DETAIL.JOUR17 + T_DETAIL.JOUR18 + T_DETAIL.JOUR19 + T_DETAIL.JOUR20 + T_DETAIL.JOUR21 + T_DETAIL.JOUR22 + T_DETAIL.JOUR23 + T_DETAIL.JOUR24 + T_DETAIL.JOUR25 + T_DETAIL.JOUR26 + T_DETAIL.JOUR27 + T_DETAIL.JOUR28 + T_DETAIL.JOUR29 + T_DETAIL.JOUR30 + T_DETAIL.JOUR31 AS Total_Jours,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR01 + T_DETAIL.JOUR02 + T_DETAIL.JOUR03 + T_DETAIL.JOUR04 + T_DETAIL.JOUR05 + T_DETAIL.JOUR06 + T_DETAIL.JOUR07 + T_DETAIL.JOUR08 + T_DETAIL.JOUR09 + T_DETAIL.JOUR10 + T_DETAIL.JOUR11 + T_DETAIL.JOUR12 + T_DETAIL.JOUR13 + T_DETAIL.JOUR14 + T_DETAIL.JOUR15 + T_DETAIL.JOUR16 + T_DETAIL.JOUR17 + T_DETAIL.JOUR18 + T_DETAIL.JOUR19 + T_DETAIL.JOUR20 + T_DETAIL.JOUR21 + T_DETAIL.JOUR22 + T_DETAIL.JOUR23 + T_DETAIL.JOUR24 + T_DETAIL.JOUR25 + T_DETAIL.JOUR26 + T_DETAIL.JOUR27 + T_DETAIL.JOUR28 + T_DETAIL.JOUR29 + T_DETAIL.JOUR30 + T_DETAIL.JOUR31 + T_DETAIL.REGUL AS Total_Jours_et_Reg,
       T_DETAIL.REGUL,
       T_Cam.ID AS ID_Cram,
       T_Cam.STATUT,
       T_Cam.T_COLLABORATEUR_ID AS ID_Cram_Coll,
       T_DETAIL.ID AS ID_Cram_Detail,
       T_DETAIL.MOIS,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR01,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR02,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR03,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR04,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR05,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR06,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR07,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR08,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR09,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR10,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR11,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR12,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR13,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR14,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR15,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR16,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR17,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR18,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR19,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR20,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR21,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR22,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR23,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR24,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR25,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR26,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR27,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR28,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR29,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR30,
       T_DETAIL.JOUR31,
       T_Supr.Suppression,
       T_Coll.TYPE
FROM T_Coll
INNER JOIN T_Cam ON  T_Cam.T_COLLABORATEUR_ID = T_Coll.ID_Coll
INNER JOIN T_DETAIL ON  T_DETAIL.T_Cam_ID = T_Cam.ID
INNER JOIN T_Type ON T_Type.TYPE = T_DETAIL.TYPE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Supr ON T_Supr.ID_Cram_Detail = T_DETAIL.ID

WHERE (T_Supr.Suppression IS NULL)

ORDER BY T_Coll.NomColl,
         T_DETAIL.AN,
         T_DETAIL.Mois_Modif,
         T_DETAIL.T_AFFAIRE_ID,
         T_DETAIL.T_LOT_ID,
         T_DETAIL.T_SOUS_LOT_ID
```

I just can't manage to make this work under MySQL !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This seems to be a complex query, if you have a lot of data you need to have proper indexes.

Comment: Are all the columns you used in `ORDER BY` indexed?

Comment: What do you mean by proper indexes ?

Comment: I think it would be helpful, if you could tell us how many records are in relations `T_Coll`, `T_DETAIL` and `T_TYpe` and do you have any indexes on let's say `T_coll.NomColl`, `T_Cam.T_COLLABORATEUR_ID`, ...

Comment: you could also try instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `IS NULL` to use a `not exists` construct. Sometimes `not exists` performs better..

Comment: Agim i'll give you this information as fast as possible ! 
However what do you mean by using not exists how would that be possible ?

Thanks alot for your help guys

Comment: t_detail table appears to be badly designed. You need to understand normalization.

Comment: I am currently working on a database which is badly designed and i'm not the designer and we can't change it at the time being. 
**For agim** -> There is in T_Coll : 2393 tables rows, in T_Detail '73931'  and in T_Type : '19'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the columns used in the joins, where clause and the order by should probably be indexed. You cannot expect any kind of decent performance in any database without indexes. There is nothing very complex about your query, so this is the most likely problem.

Do not return any columns you don't need. For instance why are you returning T_Supr.Suppression when the value will always be nulll based on your where clause?

In mysql you should look at the Explain Plan to see where the problem is with a slow query. In SQL Server look at the Execution PLan. You need to learn how to read these to effectively program in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
Where can i see the Explain Plan that you are talking about ?
**Edit** : I'll google it !

Comment: **Answer** : You guys were right it is a problem of index ! If i put a limit 0,500 it take 8 seconds and 0,1000 16 seconds approx ! 
I will need to add the correct index in order to optimize the select.

Thanks for your help, any advice is welcome =)